# How to disable other toolbar in my custom xml ribbon in Excel using VSTO

Tags: excel, vsto

Here is a situation: I created my own ribbon for Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) with some buttons. Ribbon was created in C#, VSTO, XML (not Designer). So there is a new ribbon in all of these programs with a ribbon group where are my buttons. The only exception is Excel, where there is a "Custom Toolbar" group on 1st place and my group on 2nd. The best part is that this "Cutsom Toolbar" doesn't show up on every computer I installed my add-in. 
My question: how this "Custom Toolbar" show up on a new ribbon I created and is there any way to disable it?
Ribbon code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="MyAddIn">
        <group id="GroupInclude" label="MyAddIn">
          <button id="saveMyAddIn" label="Save my file" getImage="imageButton" size="large"
             onAction="saveMyAddInButton" getEnabled="GetEnabled"
          />
          <button id="configurMyAddIn" label="MyAddIn Options" getImage="imageButton"
             onAction="configureMyAddInButton"
          />
          <button id="goToMyAddIn" label="Go to MyAddIn" getImage="imageButton"
             onAction="goToMyAddInButton"
          />
          <button id="aboutMyAddIn" label="About MyAddIn" getImage="imageButton"
             onAction="aboutMyAddInButton"
          />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see this "Custom Toolbar" in the Addins tab then you got another addin installed in the machine.
You need to remove or disable it,

To disable 
Go to File => Options => Add-Ins tab => choose COM Add-ins in the Manage dropdown and click Go, you should all the addins that are loaded.

Removing the addin completely depends on what addin it is.

Comment: But how this toolbar shows up in my ribbon, which I created? I thought there will by only things I created on my own.

Comment: Your are reusing built in ribbon tabs Addins in this line  <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="MyAddIn"> if you want to be seperate then use something like this instead of idMso attribute <tab id="TabMyTab" label="MyAddIn">

Comment: Even if you remove your addin these built in tab Addins are going to appear on those machines. These are default tab Microsoft added to add the custom command bars created in pre ribbon version of Office

Answer (score 3):

Going to the Properties of the *Tab*
 and Changing the `ControlIdType` to `Custom` fixed the issue for me.[image]

Comment: Had the same issue and this one fix it 